# ttf file is not displaying custom font in css3

Tags: html, css

I have a text box in my html page. I want to type in custom font (regional language) inside this textbox.
I add TTF file and changed the font family to this custom font. But still when I am entering into this text box, it is simply display it in English (default) only.

### css code

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:Anjali;
    src: url ('AnjaliOldLipi.ttf');

}
.font-face
{
    display:block;
    font-family:Anjali;
}
```

### HTML code

```
<input type="text" class="font-face"/>
```

How is it possible to type in English, and when entering space it is converting to custom font (regional language)? I am trying to implement same as in http://www.google.com/transliterate.

Comment: did you try putting `font-family:'Anjali'`?

Comment: Are you sure your font is even loading? Also - if you input in english characters the input will still be english - you change the font-face - not characters. Google does much more in the background.

Comment: hi easwee, could u pls explain more..

Comment: Did you try [jsFiddle](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate the `@font-face`-code? TTF only isn't that crossbrowser compatible,- this may be a part of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google Transliterate is using the following `font-family` declaration:

```
html, input, textarea {
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
```

To have the characters translated to the specified alphabet, use a JavaScript [Unicode mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/622944/how-do-i-add-a-unicode-search-to-the-javascript-console-of-a-desktop-mobile-or) from English codepoints to Anjali codepoints, such as the following:

- [Unicode Entities for Malayalam](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/malayalamchart.html)
- [Mozhi - Detailed specification](https://sites.google.com/site/cibu/mozhi/mozhi2)